# check if two columns containing sentences match and return only the matches for each dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I'm trying to match two columns in two different dataframes using this:

```
res = mergedStuff = pd.merge(df1, df2, on=['text'])
```

However for some reason, it also returns rows that are not a match.

Ideally, I would return two new dataframes containing only the rows that match in each one.

An example would look like this:

```
df1 = text                 | feature1 | feature2 | feature3 
     bananas are great     | 0        |  1       | 0  
     apples are better     | 1        |  1       | 0   
     grapes are okay       | 0        |  0       | 1  
     ice cream for the win | 1        |  0       | 1   


 df2 =      text               | feature1 | feature2 | feature3 
         bananas are great     | 0        |  1       | 0  
         apples are better     | 1        |  1       | 0   
         berries are yummy     | 0        |  0       | 1  
         ice cream for the win | 0        |  1       | 1
```

Ideally, I would now return each dataframe but only with the rows that matched on the `text` column.

Expected result:

```
df1 =     text                 | feature1 | feature2 | feature3 
         bananas are great     | 0        |  1       | 0  
         apples are better     | 1        |  1       | 0   
         ice cream for the win | 1        |  0       | 1 




 df2 =      text               | feature1 | feature2 | feature3 
         bananas are great     | 0        |  1       | 0  
         apples are better     | 1        |  1       | 0   
         ice cream for the win | 0        |  1       | 1
```

Comment: I tried your example, and it works as expected.

Comment: I know it would work on this data, but this is only dummy data and unfortunately, I cannot make my real data publicly available.

Comment: You must show at least some example that demonstrates your point. Make synthetic data if the real data is not available. The answer proposed below is equivalent to your solution. If your solution does not work, the other one won't, either.

Comment: I have tried. However, I'm still learning and if it was that easy I would have replicated the error to make an example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use `set.intersection`; then filter the common texts:

```
common = set(df1['text']) & set(df2['text'])
df1 = df1[df1['text'].isin(common)]
df2 = df2[df2['text'].isin(common)]
```

Then `df1` looks like:

```
                    text  feature1  feature2  feature3 
0      bananas are great         0         1         0
1      apples are better         1         1         0
3  ice cream for the win         1         0         1
```

and `df2` looks like:

```
                    text  feature1  feature2  feature3
0      bananas are great         0         1         0
1      apples are better         1         1         0
3  ice cream for the win         0         1         1
```